# How to execute scons in a python3 environment?

Tags: python-3.x, scons

I need to import python3 scripts within a scons script.
(I use scons v3.0.1.7)

Is there a way to execute scons with python 3 ?

The offical scons site says

> This will be the first release to support Python versions earlier than 2.7 as well as 3.5+

Something like `scons -python /usr/bin/python3` would be good to select the python interpreter.

I did not find either how to build a scons version for python3.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096321/compile-scons-in-python3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135869/managing-python-3-code-with-scons

Comment: 3.0.1.7 is not an official SCons version, 3.0.1 is so this is your distro's packaging.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the latest versions, *SCons* supports both Python2 and Python3. There is no need to recompile *SCons* itself or such. All that matters is which Python version is the default on your system.

You don't mention under which OS you're trying to get this working, so I assume a Linux for now. After the installation you can find the `scons` script in a location like `/usr/local/bin/scons` (try "`which scons`" if in doubt). The first line

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

tells your system to use the default Python version. If this is not what you want, you can simply change it to e.g.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

if you're under a Python2-default system, but want to run *SCons* with Python3 instead.

Comment: I am on macOS. Thank you, it works well! I edited the scons executable as you suggested. But maybe it is safer to create a "scons3" from the original one and then change it. I use homebrew which will certainly overwrite it on next update.

Comment: Python2 support has been dropped.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a better solution, add this to your .bash_profile:

```
alias scons3="/usr/bin/env python3 $(which scons)"
```

Comment: Also useful when you want to force Python 2.x for a newer scons which wants Python 3. (yes, I know Python 2 is EOL; trying to fix one thing at a time here)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have python 3 virtualenv installed:

```
virtualenv-3.6 venv3
venv3/bin/pip install -U setuptools wheel pip
venv3/bin/pip install scons
venv3/bin/scons
```

That allows your install to be unaffected by homebrew's updates..

Answer (score 3):

I had to edit `/usr/bin/scons` and change the shebang from

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

to

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Make sure you are in a python3 virtual environment

Comment: /usr/bin/scons is already #! /usr/bin/env python