# scons can't work on Mac throw python SyntaxError

Tags: python, macos, scons

My Mac have python2.7 by default, and the scons3 have been installed successfully.However when compile the code, it still throws a 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. i just go into the project folder and type 
`scons -q`

then it shows

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
  File "/Users/andromedae/physbam/PhysBAM_Tools/SConstruct", line 428

    print "%s has %d symbols exported"%(library_name,len(defs.keys()))

                                     ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

like it using python3? i have python3 installed by anaconda. but all i have done is:

```
python setup.py install 
cd \project
scons -q
```

Comment: Can you include the way you are executing this code? You are correct, it seems that it's executed using python3

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185262/how-to-execute-scons-in-a-python3-environment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096321/compile-scons-in-python3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135869/managing-python-3-code-with-scons

Comment: @Giannis i just go into the project folder and type scons -q

Comment: Did you try SCons 3.0.1, it should resolve this issue..

Comment: @bdbaddog my SCons is 3.0.1 :(

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure you're not running with python 3.x?  We had this issue in scons 3.0.0 and fixed it in 3.0.1 when running with python 2.7.  Looks like you are running on windows?  try running "python --version"

Comment: Also stick this right before that line: import sys; print(sys.version)  and see what output you get?

Comment: Restating 2 above: Hmm.. are you sure you're not running with python 3.x?  We had this issue in scons 3.0.0 and fixed it in 3.0.1 when running with python 2.7.  try running "python --version"

Comment: @bdbaddog sorry my scons is 3.0.0, and installed 3.0.1 it works thank u

Comment: Please mark my answer below as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Install SCons 3.0.1. The issue described was introduced in SCons 3.0.0 but fixed in 3.0.1